# How to check that a dev dependency is not needed in production?

Tags: php, testing, composer-php

Since our project needs a library to run tests, this package is listed in the `require-dev` section of `composer.json`.

```json
{
    //...
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4|^8.0",
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "cache/array-adapter": "^1.1"
    },
    //...
}
```

During a manual code review, I realised that this library is being used in our production code too.

The fix is easy, we moved the corresponding package from the `require-dev` section to the `require` section.

```json
{
    //...
    "require": {
        "php": "^7.4|^8.0",
        "cache/array-adapter": "^1.1"
    },
    "require-dev": {
    },
    //...
}
```

I'm searching an automatic way/test to avoid this kind of problem. I guess that our manual test during staging can avoid these kind of problem, but it isn't enough.

How to check that a dev-dependency isn't needed in our core-code?

Comment: Sounds like you should run some frontend blackbox tests on your application. How to do that specifically depends on your application

Comment: What you want seems like a reverse [composer-unused](https://github.com/composer-unused/composer-unused), filtering by "require" key....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This tool detects misplaced dependencies: [shipmonk/composer-dependency-analyser](https://github.com/shipmonk-rnd/composer-dependency-analyser)

- it detects dependencies used only in "tests" but placed in `require`
- it detects dependencies used in "src", but listed in `require-dev` (**your case**)
- it also detects unused & shadow dependencies

Usage is easy, it reads your `composer.json` to recognize used paths and dependencies:

```bash
composer require --dev shipmonk/composer-dependency-analyser

vendor/bin/composer-dependency-analyser
```

You can easily add this to your CI to have this automated.

Answer (score 0):

You could implement this using PHPStan (or Psalm, or any other static analyzer): if you removed the dev dependencies and then run such a tool, it would notify you about missing classes from such a dependency.

But be warned: even if this helps to write more strict code, it might need some work in the beginning to implement proper return types all over your application

---

Another idea: also remove dev dependencies and run a usual test suite like PHPUnit or Behat.

Comment: Upvote: Your solution seems very interesting. Before accepting the answer, saturday, I will use our project (before the fix), then I will deploy it without dev dependencies. So, I will check if PHPStan finds the missing class. Thanks for your help, I didn't know that PHPStan can do this kind of checks. !

Comment: The secret is: "this kind of check" is a pretty common one for PHPStan, **if** you have configured return types (or other places where the class is used) properly, as it simply states: "You are using a class that could not be found"

Comment: I created a test and it fails when my library isn't installed. thank you ! We had phpstan it in our deployment on staging. It works fine!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could do it with [deptrac](https://packagist.org/packages/qossmic/deptrac). Although it's generally used to track internal architectural dependencies, nothing stops you from configuring it to track external dependencies.

It would require you manually configuring the "dev" layer with different "collectors", one for each dev dependency namespace, and a base layer for your `App` namespace.

Anything in `App` that depends on the `dev` layer would be a violation, unless explicitly allowed. You could even put this in CI (which is a common use-case of deptrac), where any violation would stop the deployment.

The configuration would be something like this (untested):

```yaml
paths:
  - ./src/
exclude_files: ~
layers:
  - name: App
    collectors:
      - type: className
        regex: App\\.*
  - name: Dependencies
    collectors:
      - type: className
        regex: Symfony\\Bundle\\MakerBundle\\.*
      - type: className
        regex: Cache\\Adapter\\PHPArray\\.*
```

Comment: The thing is: does this catch **all** possible kinds of missing dependencies automatically, or only those that are explicitly configured? If a colleague starts using a class from a dev dependency, and **not** adds this namespace to the deptrac configuration, would this be caught after all?

Comment: Dev-Dependencies would need to be added manually to deptrack configuration. The scenario you posit is one where another developer a) requires --dev new-library b) omits adding it to the corresponding deptrack layer c) use the dev dependency in non-dev code. It's almost malicious behaviour. And dev dependencies are generally few enough as to be easily tracked.

Comment: One could write a script to automatically add dev dependencies to the "dev" layer automatically... although in general it would be overkill, IMO.